# where to find the postgresql 13 error logs

Tags: postgresql

now I tweak the PostgreSQL 13 config like this:

```
log_statement = 'all'

# This is used when logging to stderr:
logging_collector = on        # Enable capturing of stderr and csvlog
                    # into log files. Required to be on for
                    # csvlogs.
                    # (change requires restart)

# These are only used if logging_collector is on:
log_directory = 'log'            # directory where log files are written,
                    # can be absolute or relative to PGDATA
log_filename = 'postgresql-%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S.log'    # log file name pattern,
                    # can include strftime() escapes
log_file_mode = 0600            # creation mode for log files,
                    # begin with 0 to use octal notation
#log_truncate_on_rotation = off        # If on, an existing log file with the
                    # same name as the new log file will be
                    # truncated rather than appended to.
                    # But such truncation only occurs on
                    # time-driven rotation, not on restarts
                    # or size-driven rotation.  Default is
                    # off, meaning append to existing files
                    # in all cases.
#log_rotation_age = 1d            # Automatic rotation of logfiles will
                    # happen after that time.  0 disables.
#log_rotation_size = 10MB        # Automatic rotation of logfiles will
                    # happen after that much log output.
                    # 0 disables.
```

I can find the log in the PostgreSQL data folder, but now I am facing a problem that I could not find the error log. For example, I passed a syntax error sql to PostgreSQL, now I only found the error syntax sql in the log file. But I could not find the PostgreSQL log information that shows the sql that has the syntax error. Where to find the error information in PostgreSQL? What should I do to find it? For example, I tweak the sql like this:

```
2022-07-20 14:19:31.484 GMT [11666] LOG:  execute __diesel_stmt_0: SELECT *, count_estimate('select * from article') FROM  (SELECT "article"."id", "article"."user_id", "article"."title", "article"."author", "article"."guid", "article"."created_time", "article"."updated_time", "article"."link", "article"."pub_time", "article"."sub_source_id", "article"."cover_image", "article"."channel_reputation", "article"."editor_pick" FROM "article" WHERE "article"."id" < $1 AND to_tsvector($2) @@ to_tsquery($3) ORDER BY "article"."created_time" DESC LIMIT $4 OFFSET $5) t
2022-07-20 14:19:31.484 GMT [11666] DETAIL:  parameters: $1 = '2787285', $2 = '''dolphin1zhcfg'', title', $3 = '历史', $4 = '20', $5 = '0'
```

the `dolphin1zhcfg` did not exists, where is the error message? the backend app did not capture the error, it only return null results. I have already tried to using command like this to find out:

```
tail -f postgresql-2022-07-20_123009.log |grep -C 20 "ERROR"
```

no error information. I expect I could found the error information like this:

```
SQL Error [42704]: ERROR: text search configuration "dolphin1zhcfg" does not exist
  Position: 459

Error position: line: 24 pos: 458
```

Comment: Well, if  you have a condition that makes the query return no rows that's not a syntax error. So nothing is logged.

Comment: the sql syntax is error, not no rows return. @a_horse_with_no_name I have edit my question and make it more clear.

Comment: The query you show is not using dolphin1zhcfg as a text search configuration.  It is using it as the document text, with default_text_search_config as the config.  To use a non-default config, you need to use the two-argument form of to_tsvector, which you don't do in the query you show.  So you don't see an ERROR because there is no error.

Comment: I have passed `'''dolphin1zhcfg'', title'` as the parameter, which already contains 2 parameter, should not do it like that? @jjanes

Comment: No, you can't cram two parameters into one parameter.  That is just one piece of text, with some embedded single quotes and commas in it.

Comment: I am understand what exactly happen with my situation. Thank you!@jjanes